# Clear image cache created by <Image>

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, windows-phone-8.1

If I have an element like this in a Windows Store or Windows Phone application:

```
<Image Source="{Binding UrlToWebServer}" />
```

the image is cached locally. This is great. But how do I remove all cached images on disc from code?

Comment: Where did you find the image is cached on disc. As far as I know, the XAML framework will associate the URI to avoid decode one image multiple time,  but it will not cache the web images to disc.

Comment: If I put my device in flight mode and restart my application the images are still loaded so they have to be stored somewhere. I found my files in {User}\AppData\Local\Packages\{PackageName}\AC\INetCache. Disc Cleanup seems to be able to remove these files but would be nice if I could it from my application as well.

Answer (score 2):

You just have to set the imagesource to NULL

Something like this:

```
BitmapImage bitmapImage = myimage.Source as BitmapImage;
bitmapImage.UriSource = null;
myimage.Source = null;
```

This works for me. [Here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/swick/archive/2011/04/07/image-tips-for-windows-phone-7.aspx) you can find mor infos handling images (section Image Caching for example).

Comment: Hmm…. Really? :-) I understand that the image will disappear from the screen but will it also remove it from disc? Also I want to remove all cached images, not for an individual element (I’ve clarified my question).

Comment: Hmm.. I have no idea how to clear all cached images at once. The code snippet I posted just helped me with some memory issues.

Comment: If all the Images use either the same `BitmapImage` or the same `UriSource` then setting them to null will tell the garbage collector that they should be removed from ram....So this should work.

Answer (score 0):

Hi it´s a little bit late to answer this question but you can use this class to delete the cache of a specific files or all if you want

this is the class helper

```
 class CacheCleanup : IDisposable
{
    private DispatcherTimer cleanCacheTimer;
    public CacheCleanup(TimeSpan? cleanInterval = null)
    {
        if (!cleanInterval.HasValue)
            cleanInterval = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(0.2);

        cleanCacheTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
        cleanCacheTimer.Interval = cleanInterval.Value;
        cleanCacheTimer.Tick += CleanCacheTimer_Tick;
        cleanCacheTimer.Start();
    }

    private void CleanCacheTimer_Tick(object sender, object e)
    {
        try
        {
            StorageFolder localDirectory = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
            string[] tmpCacheDirectories = Directory.GetDirectories(localDirectory.Path + "\\..\\ac\\inetcache");
            foreach (string dir in tmpCacheDirectories)
            {
                string[] tmpCacheFilesPng = Directory.GetFiles(dir, "*.png");
                foreach (string file in tmpCacheFilesPng)
                {

                        try
                        {
                            File.Delete(file);
                            Debug.WriteLine("Deleted png: " + file);
                        }
                        catch (Exception) { }
                }
                string[] tmpCacheFilesJpg = Directory.GetFiles(dir, "*.jpg");
                foreach (string file in tmpCacheFilesJpg)
                {

                    try
                    {
                        File.Delete(file);
                        Debug.WriteLine("Deleted jpg: " + file);
                    }
                    catch (Exception) { }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { Debug.WriteLine("ERROR CLEANING CACHE: " + ex.Message); }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (cleanCacheTimer != null)
        {
            cleanCacheTimer.Stop();
            cleanCacheTimer = null;
        }
    }
}
```

and this is the  way  how  you can call this class in some part of your c# code

```
CacheCleanup cacheCleanup = new CacheCleanup();
```